# Cannot find BLE dll files in windows 11

Tags: c#, windows, dll

I was trying to follow this tutorial by 'Cornel Human' on Youtube to connect to a BLE sensor with C#.
He referenced a dll from this path:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5`
He has .dll files there...but both my PCs do not have them (they instead have .xml files which cannot be referenced).
Any idea how I can solve this?

I tried a lot of stuff and looked it up on google as well.
I was not able to get the DLLs no matter what.
Can anyone help me solve this or point me in the right direction?
Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you might need a NuGet reference.

Comment: Thanks @500-InternalServerError this helped but now I have a new problem which is saying:Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NETSDK1130 Windows.UI.Shell.SecurityAppManagerContract.winmd cannot be referenced. Referencing a Windows Metadata component directly when targeting .NET 5 or higher is not supported. For more information, see https://aka.ms/netsdk1130 quickBLEtest C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets 1162

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/interop/5.0/built-in-support-for-winrt-removed